# Spring-boot doesn't create tables in h2 - JPA/Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2

I have tried to follow this guide to store my data in the h2 database with Spring Boot. https://memorynotfound.com/spring-boot-spring-data-jpa-hibernate-h2-web-console

But it looks like the DB tables aren't created. It also doesn't get an error message, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I tried to add `@EntityScan`, but it's not working.

*Update

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/console
spring.h2.console.settings.trace=false
spring.h2.console.settings.web-allow-others=false

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:example-app;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.datasource.platform=h2
spring.datasource.username = sa
spring.datasource.password =
spring.datasource.driverClassName = org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=false
```

Comment: `ddl-auto: drop-create`

Comment: show the relevant configuration.

Comment: please show your application.properties file

Comment: I am using the same config like the tutorial.

Comment: How do you know that the tables aren't created? Have you tried to use the h2-console? If yes, take a picture(or connection information) of how you are using it?

Comment: Solved. @ThiagoChagas put me on the right path. I made a mistake in the URL.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that You have this config property (it is automatically like that for h2 though):

```
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
```